# Select an mp3 file from SD card

Tags: android

I need to ask the user to select a media file from his SD card for playing. The following code doesn't work:
edit:
after I choose a mp3 file from the sd card folder I can't start him (play him). I think that the problem is that it doesn't entering to the "onActivityResult" function.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setType("audio/*");
                    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_OK);    



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri uri =data.getData();
        if(uri!=null) {
            try {
                song.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
                song.prepare();
                pl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        song.start();
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(CONTEXT_RESTRICTED, RESULT_OK, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the language a bit but adding details about any errors that you see will be even more helpful. More specifically what do you mean when you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Hi,after I choose a mp3 file from the sd card folder I can't start him (play him). I think that the problem is that it doesn't entering to the "onActivityResult" fonction. I hope the describe is better now. Ty!

Comment: Yes it is better. You don't see an error, right? You are able to select an mp3 file but it won't play. Correct?

Comment: Yes it's right.

Comment: Start with tracing your code with the debugger to see exactly what happens. It's hard to say what goes wrong by just looking at a code snippet.

Comment: @Himanshu so, can you help me with that? it's really necessary for my project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't include definitions of some variables so I added my own and it played. Try this:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setType("audio/*");
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            if (uri != null) {
                try {
                    MediaPlayer song = new MediaPlayer();
                    song.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
                    song.prepare();
                    song.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(CONTEXT_RESTRICTED, RESULT_OK, data);
    }
}
```

MediaPlayer Docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

Comment: Ty, I'll try this now.

Comment: The code above it should have been in another method, which you probably didn't include here. Assuming your original code compiled, no other changes needed.

Comment: Could you please post your complete code instead and any errors that you see.